# Getting names of all private repos through GitHub API

Tags: api, github, zsh

I'm trying to get a list of all names in a repo that I have access to. I tried running:

```
curl -u username:pw -X GET  https://api.github.com/orgs/org_name/repos?per_page=100 >> list.txt
```

but I get the error: `zsh: no matches found: https://api.github.com/org/org_name/repos?per_page=100`

All I want is a list of the repos... no other information. Can't seem to figure it out. I'm new to programming and started using API like.. 1 hour ago? Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your shell (zsh) is interpreting the URL as a path and complaining because it doesn't match any files.  You can solve this by placing quotes around it.  In this case, either single or double quotes will work.

Comment: So it works now, but when I run the command I only get public repos.

Comment: I think you will have to include API authorization key with your curl command [github auth](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication)

Comment: Yeah, if you're only seeing public repos, then you have an authorization problem.  Make sure you're using a personal access token or OAuth token, not a password, for the API.